# Parse fixed length data from text into database

Tags: sql-server, parsing, loops, text

I have text file with some data that need to be read into database. Data inside the file is as follows:

```
00000A0011Nike running shoes00000A0012Nike store mo city12345B0001EMC Truck         
12345B0002BH78545789785     12345B0003NH170323032015060012345C0011Steve Jones Shoe's
12345C0012Company, Tel17545812345C001312,Fax:66234544-4812345D0001Mrs. Mary Wilson, Off 19
45781B0001EMC Truck         45781B0002BH78545789785     45781B0003NH1703230320150600
45781C0011Steve Jones Shoe's45781C0012Company, Tel17545845781C001312,Fax:66234544-48
45781D0001Mrs. Mary Wilson, Off 19
```

Each line is same length with 3 sections in it. Each section has different kind of data, here is the interpretation of the data:

```
TransactionID Char(5)  
Record Char(2)  
Record Counter Number(3)  
    - A0  Data Fields
      011 Sender information  Char(18)
      012 Sender Location     Char(18)
    - B0  Data Fields
      001 Vehicle Type        Char(18)
      002 Destination         Char(05)
      002 Package Weight      Number(05)
      002 Package Data        Number(03)
      002 Filler              Char(05)
    - C0 Data Fields
      011 Receiver Address    Char(18)
      012 Receiver Address    Char(18)
      013 Receiver Address    Char(18)
    - D0 Data Fields
      001 Contact Person      Char(18)
```

I have the above information saved in the database, which I lode on run time and then as user upload the file, I am trying to read the line, and read each block and try to extract data from it.
As of now, I am kind of no able to separate transactions, as each transaction must be a separate row in the table. Also, some of the data is split across multiple blocks, i.e. "C0" field types.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SQL isn't the best place to have to do string processing but this doesn't look too difficult. I don't think you can easily do it in a set based manner but looping over each line on the input it should be doable. Here's some pseudo code that should get you started;

```
@TransactionId = substring(@Input, 1, 5)
@CurrentInputPosition = 6

while (@CurrentInputPosition < len(@Input)
begin
    @Record = substring(@Input, @CurrentInputPosition, 2)

    if (@Record = 'A0')
    begin
        @SenderInformation = substring(@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2, 18)
        @SenderLocation = substring(@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18, 18)
        @CurrentInputPosition + @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18 + 18

        -- Save A0 record data

    end
    else if (@Record = 'B0')
    begin
        @VehicleType = substring(@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2, 18)
        @Destination = substring(@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18, 5)
        @Package Weight = substring(@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18 + 5, 5)
        @Package Data = substring(@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18 + 5 + 5, 3)
        @Filler = substring(@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18 + 5 + 5 + 3, 5)
        @CurrentInputPosition + @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18 + 5 + 5 + 3 + 5

        -- Save B0 record data

    end
    else if (@Record = 'C0')
    begin

        @ReceiverAddress1 = (@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2, 18)    Char(18)
        @ReceiverAddress2 = (@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18, 18)    Char(18)
        @ReceiverAddress3 = (@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18 + 18, 18)    Char(18)
        @CurrentInputPosition + @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18 + 18 + 18

        -- Save C0 record data

    end
    else if (@Record = 'D0')
    begin
        @ContactPerson = substring(@Input, @CurrentInputPosition + 2, 18)
        @CurrentInputPosition + @CurrentInputPosition + 2 + 18

        -- Save D0 record data

    end
end
```

Note - it's pseudo code, you will have to flesh it out with a cursor/loop, declares etc. Don't add a comment and tell me it doesn't run ;)

Comment: Thanks, it's a good place to start, but I wanted to share one thing. The transaction ID is part of the file. I am suppose to read the complete data (including transaction ID) from the file, I don't have anything but file structure information. Therefore, I cannot use an input parameter in this case.

Comment: @input is a varchar that holds a complete line from the file, including the transaction ID.

Comment: Which I did is that I am reading data line by line and dividing each line into 3 separate lines, writing it into new file. Then I am reading each line from new file and based on "Record Char" I am updating the associated table/record. Still working on it to refine it. Thank for the TSQL, next task is to migrate c# code into a stored procedure.

Comment: Nice, now I have got the idea on how to do it in a mixed mode, with C# & SQL together. I can read each line from the new file and pass it on to the procedure. However, it looks challenging to iterate through the other table (where structure information is stored) and check each record anyway. I will try this and post the outcome, if I am successful. Thanks again!

Comment: If this answer has helped you then please help me and accept this answer. See [Answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).